# Android crashes at Unable to open zip file: /data/app/, Android 10, RenderScript

Tags: android, android-studio, renderscript

I am desperate with this issue and as a beginner I need help. My app gets app notification access permission and is running smoothly with active users.

**When the crash occurs:** I resolved some issues, but when I test it, after upgrading to the new version of the app on one of my test devices, I receive the below crash, as soon as the app runs the first time after the update.

**What is the effect of the crash:** The size of the views on the screen also changes, and strings resources are loaded incorrectly, one instead of another. Some other resources are also all messed up.

**Does it always happens?** When during the upgrade, app notification permission is off, no such error appears. I'm really desperate because of these errors and the update I have to release soon. When I run F5 the app on the new version again, no such error occurs again.

**Concern:** If I release the app, the same issue happens to users.

**Questions:** Any idea why this happens, what causes it, or how to prevent it?

```
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.803 18916-18916/myapp.package I/Choreographer: Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.823 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/renderscript/RenderScript;->getMinorID()J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.823 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pa: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;->getRuntime()Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.823 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pa: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;->registerNativeAllocation(I)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.823 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pa: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;->registerNativeFree(I)V (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.824 18916-18916/myapp.package E/System: Unable to open zip file: /data/app/myapp.package-j3fOrkqQq-YZuxNkVmXWOA==/base.apk
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.833 18916-18916/myapp.package E/System: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/app/myapp.package-j3fOrkqQq-YZuxNkVmXWOA==/base.apk (No such file or directory)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:265)
            at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:187)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:169)
            at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:106)
            at libcore.io.ClassPathURLStreamHandler.<init>(ClassPathURLStreamHandler.java:46)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement.maybeInit(DexPathList.java:864)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement.findNativeLibrary(DexPathList.java:885)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findLibrary(DexPathList.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findLibrary(BaseDexClassLoader.java:270)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1060)
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1007)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1667)
            at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.internalCreate(RenderScript.java:1408)
            at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1599)
            at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1549)
            at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1525)
            at androidx.renderscript.RenderScript.create(RenderScript.java:1512)
            at com.qhutch.elevationimageview.ElevationImageView.onAttachedToWindow(ElevationImageView.kt:136)
            at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19614)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3439)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1800)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7751)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7582)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.835 18916-18916/myapp.package V/RenderScript_jni: RS native mode
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.839 18916-18916/myapp.package V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load libRSSupportIO.so, USAGE_IO not supported
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.839 18916-18916/myapp.package V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load BLAS lib, ONLY BNNM will be supported: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/myapp.package-j3fOrkqQq-YZuxNkVmXWOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/myapp.package-j3fOrkqQq-YZuxNkVmXWOA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/myapp.package-j3fOrkqQq-YZuxNkVmXWOA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libblasV8.so"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.840 18916-18916/myapp.package D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService()
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.850 18916-18916/myapp.package D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: IRenderScriptDevice::getService() returned 0x7bfa5ff260
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.850 18916-18916/myapp.package D/RenderScript HIDL Adaptation: HIDL successfully loaded.
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.858 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.verbose"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.854 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pax: type=1400 audit(0.0:30290): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23238 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.864 18916-18916/myapp.package I/chatty: uid=10419(myapp.package) identical 1 line
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.864 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pax: type=1400 audit(0.0:30292): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23238 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.nointrinsicblur"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.nointrinsicblas"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.noperfhint"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.dump_setup"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.noprofile"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.dump_bitcode"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.force_finish"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.disable_expand"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.use_fast_math"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.blurimpl"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.866 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.noobjcache"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.864 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pax: type=1400 audit(0.0:30293): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=23238 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c163,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.868 18916-19128/myapp.package E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.rs.notextures"
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.868 18916-19128/myapp.package V/RenderScript: Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriver_adreno.so
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.870 18916-18916/myapp.package W/tivesystems.pa: Accessing hidden field Landroid/renderscript/RenderScriptCacheDir;->mCacheDir:Ljava/io/File; (greylist, JNI, allowed)
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.870 18916-18916/myapp.package D/RenderScript: Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/myapp.package/code_cache
    2020-11-15 01:50:54.955 18916-18916/myapp.package D/RecommendationItemFragm: onCreateView: Selected ***** recommendations ***** are: 3093 id is:5093
```

Here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

// Add the Firebase Crashlytics plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyAppName.Package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 32
        versionName "1.32 release"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion = var
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation('com.github.worker8:tourguide:1.0.19-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'

//    implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'com.github.vicpinm:activeandroidrx:3.1.9'
    implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.2.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation project(':mood-tracker')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
    implementation 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9.4'
    implementation 'com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.bq:markerseekbar:v0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.HasanMhdAmin:StepsIndicatorView:v0.9.1'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.qhutch.elevationimageview:elevationimageview:2.3'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:3.0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:17.1.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.4.0'


    implementation 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.3.3'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'

    implementation 'me.rishabhkhanna:CustomToggle:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'


//    def work_version = "2.4.0"
    def work_version = "1.0.1"
    // (Java only)
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0'
    // Kotlin + coroutines
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: It appears that `com.qhutch.elevationimageview` is related. Before changing your gradle file, I would confirm that a clean build of the new code and then attempting to update old version creates a crash consistently (for repeatability). From: https://github.com/qhutch/ElevationImageView I see that you are missing `renderscriptTargetApi 18` from your build.gradle file. There may be some Renderscript bytecode compatibility issue you've encountered by not setting the `renderscriptTargetApi` the same as your library.

Comment: The clean build also create the same issue only if the notification access is enabled before. If this permission is disabled, the error does not occur.

Comment: Although I have elevationimageview in my Gradle, searching for it in the project, it has not been used in the source at all.